# Gnuplot : shift each values of each axis by one

Tags: linux, plot, gnuplot

I need your help for sometings :

I've this type of data :

```
2019-10-08-13-37    /dev/hd1    256.00  26.25   /home
2019-10-08-18-00    /dev/hd1    256.00  25.86   /home
2019-10-09-00-00    /dev/hd1    256.00  25.68   /home
2019-10-09-06-00    /dev/hd1    256.00  25.5    /home
2019-10-09-12-00    /dev/hd1    256.00  26.32   /home
2019-10-09-18-00    /dev/hd1    256.00  26.14   /home
```

I've this gnuplot script :

```
set terminal pngcairo truecolor size 7330, 340  background rgb "#eff1f0" font "Arial"

set output "/xxx/xxx/www/xxx/foo.png"
set style line 1 \
    linecolor rgb '#0060ad' \
    linetype 1 linewidth 1 \
    pointtype 7 pointsize 1

set size 1, 1
set key outside vertical center right
set datafile separator ";"
set xlabel "DATE" font ",1"
set xtics rotate by 90 offset 0, -2 font ",7"
set format y "%g"


plot "/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/data.txt" using 3:xtic(1) with linespoints linestyle 1 title "total"
```

That allow to display this graph :
[image]

I would like to decale each value like that :

```
254
|
|
253
|
|___my_date1___my_date2
```

But I don't know how to do that... Could you show me ?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean. Do you mean rotating the date or removing the time or both?

Comment: I would like to shift each value in order to don't have the first values on the point of intersection. Like that : https://zupimages.net/up/20/09/lr1p.png

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix to your question might be:

```
set offsets 1,1,1,1   # left, right, top, bottom
```

In gnuplot console check `help offsets`.

If you are plotting time data I wouldn't use `xtic(1)` for the xtic labels. If you have thousands of data points you will have thousands of of xtics.

Try the code below. gnuplot will autoscale and you might not need the offsets.

**Code:**

```
### plotting time data
reset session

$Data <<EOD
2019-10-08-13-37    /dev/hd1    256.00  26.25   /home
2019-10-08-18-00    /dev/hd1    256.00  25.86   /home
2019-10-09-00-00    /dev/hd1    256.00  25.68   /home
2019-10-09-06-00    /dev/hd1    256.00  25.5    /home
2019-10-09-12-00    /dev/hd1    256.00  26.32   /home
2019-10-09-18-00    /dev/hd1    256.00  26.14   /home
EOD

myTimeFmt = "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M"
set format x "%Y-%m-%d\n%H:%M" time

plot $Data u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):4 w lp pt 7 title "my data"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]